# Change registry key before starting a windows service

Tags: windows, service, batch-file, startup

I have to find a way to change some registry keys BEFORE a specific Windows Service get started after a reboot.

The service startup is set to automatic and my solution needs run only at the system startup (well... it could also be executed on manual service startup but it's not mandatory).

I know my registry keys could be set using a batch file and a .reg file but I would like to know how and when to trigger the batch file if I want it to be executed before my service.

For me, the simplest solution is always the best but if there's no other options, I can write something in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to set the service to manual, set your reg keys, then start the service.

```
reg add HKLM\yourkeys
net start yourservice
```

Comment: Interesting... and how to make sure those command lines gets executed at startup?

Comment: You can put it in the registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` or `HKCU` if you prefer. Just create new string value, give it a name and for the value put the path to your batch file.

Comment: Or if you prefer cmd :) `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "batch" /d "C:\batch.bat" /f`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [service dependencies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888): Create your own service that does whatever you want (manipulate registry in your case), and add a dependency from the target service to your new service.

Answer (score 0):

I would try powershell startup script which could change the registy keys and then start your service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj130675.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315270.aspx

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_service_start.htm